# Highcharts redundant time data with multiple axes

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I'm getting my datetime data, for a Highchart multiple axis chart, from a MySql database, using php, thus:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$voltage = $row['vSmall'];
$loadVoltage = $row['loadVoltageBigPanel'];
$dob = strtotime($row['dob']);
$current = $row['currentBigPanel'];

$dob *= 1000; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time

   $tData[] = "[$dob,$voltage]";
   $vData[] = "[$dob,$loadVoltage]";
   $cData[] = "[$dob,$current]";

}
```

This is being inserted into the chart thus:

```
    series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: [<?php echo join($tData, ',') ?>],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' V'
    }

  },{

    name: 'Load Voltage',
    type: 'area',
    data: [<?php echo join($vData, ',') ?>],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' V'
    },

  },{

    name: 'Current',
    type: 'spline',
    lineColor: '#ff0000',
    yAxis: 1,
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    data: [<?php echo join($cData, ',') ?>],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' ma',
        borderColor:'#000000',

    }, etc...
```

which obviously leads to the same datetime data being output for every axis, e.g.

```
    series: [{
    showInLegend: true,
    type: 'area',
    data: [[1489415941000,5.34],[1489416001000,5.34],[1489416061000,5.33],[1489416121000,5.33],[1489416181000,5.33],[1489416241000,5.32],[1489416301000,5.32],[1489416361000,5.32],[1489416421000,5.32],[1489416481000,5.32]],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' V'
    }

  },{

    name: 'Load Voltage',
    type: 'area',
    data: [[1489415941000,8.00],[1489416001000,8.00],[1489416061000,8.00],[1489416121000,8.00],[1489416181000,7.94],[1489416241000,7.98],[1489416301000,7.98],[1489416361000,7.98],[1489416421000,7.98],[1489416481000,7.98]],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' V'
    },

  },{

    name: 'Current',
    type: 'spline',
    lineColor: '#ff0000',
    yAxis: 1,
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    data: [[1489415941000,7.10],[1489416001000,7.00],[1489416061000,6.90],[1489416121000,6.80],[1489416181000,5.30],[1489416241000,6.20],[1489416301000,6.50],[1489416361000,6.40],[1489416421000,6.20],[1489416481000,6.10]],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' ma',
        borderColor:'#000000',

    },
```

I've applied a query limit to this example, for obvious reasons, but as can be seen, the time and date data is replicated un-necessarily.

My datasets are getting reasonably large now, and this is incredibly wasteful, as well as causing javascript events, such as selecting a range, to run slower and slower.

I want to add further axes, but this is going to be even more wasteful, to keep outputting the time data over and over, for every subsequent axis.

I've Googled, pored over the online documentation, and searched on multiple forums, but cannot find a way to tell Highcharts to use a single output array of datetime, and instruct subsequent axes, "Hey! Use the previously output datetime array!"

I must be missing something obvious, because I can't see the developers not handling this situation, thereby causing potentially huge amounts of replicated (and thus entirely redundant) data to be output into the page???

I hope I've explained this clearly. Hopefully, the code snippets illustrate what I'm talking about.

Max

Comment: I have exactly your same problem. Did you find a good solution? I already know about the pointStart and pointInterval properties (I've RTFM ;) ), but I can't apply this to my data, 'cause the time interval is not always regular (data is collected by a system that sometimes may go offline), so even your solution _get the first and last timestamps from the table, perform a calculation on the time difference_ can't go for my scenario. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, in part because it looks like you are using the word `axis` when what you really mean is `series`.

If I understand correctly, you don't want to specify the time stamp for each data point, in each series, because they're the same in each series.

IF your timestamps occur at regular intervals (e.g. once per day, once per hour, once per minute, etc.), you can use the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties.

`pointStart` is a time stamp that specifies the date/time of the first data point.

`pointInterval` is a number, in milliseconds, that specifies the amount of time between each point.

Then you can provide your data is simple arrays of `y` values instead of an array of arrays of `x`/`y` pairs.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval

If your timestamps are not at regular intervals, there is not a clean solution that I know of, and your observation:

> ...but cannot find a way to tell Highcharts to use a single output array
>   of datetime, and instruct subsequent axes, "Hey! Use the previously
>   output datetime array!"

Is correct - there is not such a property to tell different **series** to use a single array of x values.

Comment: I beg your pardon, I'm using the wrong terminology, and stand corrected.

My timestamps are a minute apart at the moment, but that may well change, and I can't guarantee they will be equidistant.

Nevertheless, it may well behove me to get the first and last timestamps from the table, perform a calculation on the time difference, and then use the technique you describe above.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.


Max